# Thread wait sleep and notify

Tags: multithreading, sleep, wait, notify

i'm creating a simple timer,i have some basic knowledge about thread.
i can stop the currently sunning thread by wait but can't able to notify it shows"illegalmonitorstateexception".

```
'import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*; 
 import java.applet.Applet;
 /* <applet code = "TimerClass" width = 800 height = 600></applet>*/
 public class TimerClass extends Applet implements Runnable, ActionListener
 {
Thread t1;
int i;
TextField sec;
Button start;
Button stop;
boolean isStop;
boolean isAlive;
public void init()
{
    sec = new TextField(10);
    start = new Button("Start");
    stop = new Button("Stop");
    add(sec);
    add(start);
    add(stop);
    start.addActionListener(this);
    stop.addActionListener(this);
    isStop = true;
    t1 = new Thread(this);
}
public void startThread()
{
    t1.start();
    isAlive = true;
}
public void awake()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isAlive());
        synchronized(t1)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().notify();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    //Thread.interrupted();
}
synchronized public void run()
{
    do
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            i += 1;
            sec.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            System.out.println(i);
            if(isStop)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException  ie)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }while(isStop != true); 
}
public void stopThread()
{
    try
    {
        synchronized(t1)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().wait();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ie)
    {

    }
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if(ae.getActionCommand() == "Start")
    {
        if(!isAlive)
        {
            isStop = false;
            System.out.println("Thread start");
            startThread();
        }
        else
        {
            isStop = false;
            System.out.println("Thread start again" + isStop);
            awake();
        }
    }
    if(ae.getActionCommand() == "Stop")
    {
        isStop = true;
        stopThread();
    }
}
}
```

need help with this.

Comment: You can use wait() method for the synced class. synchronized(t1)
        {
            t1.currentThread().wait();
        }

Comment: i try that,the problem is in notify i think i only have to notify the thread it start again and i also check that the thread is alive when i notifying it.But it can't continue again after wait.

Comment: This question is asked several times a day. Please google more or google better.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TimerClass {
    Thread t1;
    //fileds, initialisation....

    public void init() {
        //Do Something here...
        t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();
        isAlive = true;
    }

    public void stopThread() throws InterrupterException {
        try {
            //Do Something here...
            synchronized(t1) {
                t1.wait();
            }
        }catch(InterrupterException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void startThread() throws InterrupterException {
        try {
            //Do Something here...
            synchronized(t1) {
                t1.notify()
            }
        }catch(InterrupterException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

If I'm nothing forgot, it should be look something like this

Comment: well already try that one too and you can't use wait without a try-catch block.it throws a InterruptedException.

Comment: @sank sorry, forgot about try-catch blocks. Of course you need to add them.